# Windows style snipping tool on linux

Tags: image-processing

Is there any snipping tool available on linux that's similar, or works similarly to win10's?

I mean, using a button combination to bring up the snipping tool box (like win10's `win + shift + s`) and then automatically have it in my clipboard, such that I can instantly paste it into, say, skype to somebody?

My linux distro (mint) has a screenshot application, but it's really slow and tedious to use, nowhere near as fluid as win10's.

Comment: I use Screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot tool or shutter or flameshot

Comment: You probably mean "text snippets"? Be aware that many users here may not have any experience with win10.

Comment: ksnip for the win (not the windoze)

Comment: I don't know why there is not one in Mint. There is one in Ubuntu, baked right into Gnome-Shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `xfce-screenshooter` on Xubuntu 20.04 (it's part of the default install).

The `xfce-screenshooter -r` 'select a region' command is assigned to the keyboard shortcut 'Shift+Print'. I believe this is a default.

It's very quick and simple to use - 'Shift+Print', select the area you want, the default action after selection is 'Copy to the clipboard' - so just hit enter and your selection is in the clipboard ready to paste where ever you want.

Comment: Thanks. After reading the help page for `xfce-screenshooter` I made a new shortcut for `xfce-screenshooter -r -c` to instantly put it into the clipboard.